# Using array_search for multi value search

Tags: php

```
  $array_subjected_to_search =array(
  array(
          'name' => 'flash',
          'type' => 'hero'
      ),

  array(
          'name' => 'zoom',
          'type' => 'villian'
      ),

  array(
          'name' => 'snart',
          'type' => 'antihero'
      ),
  array(
        'name' => 'flash',
        'type' => 'camera'
      )
  );
  $key = array_search('flash', array_column($array_subjected_to_search, 'name'));
  var_dump($array_subjected_to_search[$key]);
```

This works fine, but is there a way to search using multiple values: eg. get key where `name='flash' && type='camera'` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is there a way to search using multiple values: eg. get key where
> name='flash' && type='camera' ?

Simply with `array_keys` function:

```
$result_key = array_keys($array_subjected_to_search, [ 'type' => 'camera','name' => 'flash']);
print_r($result_key);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function accepts an array as parameters the following will work for the use case you provided.

```
$array_subjected_to_search =array(
  array(
    'name' => 'flash',
    'type' => 'hero'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'zoom',
    'type' => 'villian'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'snart',
    'type' => 'antihero'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'flash',
    'type' => 'camera'
  )
);
$compare = array(
    'name'=>'flash',
    'type'=>'camera'
);
$key = array_search($compare, $haystack);
var_dump($haystack[$key]);
```

Note: your current search will not function correctly it will always return the zero index because the array_search returns 0 or false.

```
$key = array_search('flash', array_column($array_subjected_to_search, 'name'));
var_dump($array_subjected_to_search[$key]);
```

Comment: this only works when you have all values of an array. If this array contains more than the search values, you wont find it.

Comment: @Dwza because the user asked specifically for a way to search an `&&` use case then this method works exactly as intented. If the `$compare` array has more values than what is in the haystack then of course it won't find it because it is not meeting the requirements of `&&`

Comment: Than of course, but I mean when the haystack array contains more fields, this won't work as well. Lets assume $array_subjected_to_search-elements contains also an id field or some, the compare can't find the array either. See this example https://repl.it/repls/HardtofindDarkorchidKnowledge

Answer (score 1):

I think I would just make my own function using a loop that will just retrieve the array I want based on either one or two parameters.

```
function getValueMatch($array, $val1, $val2 = false, $type = 'name')
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $row) {
            # See note below, but it might be handy to have a reversible key name
            if($row[$type] == $val1) {
                if($val2) {
                    # You can put a changeable key name to reverse-find
                    # It might be helpful to search for the other key first
                    # at some point, best to keep your options open!
                    $altVar = ($type == 'name')? 'type' : 'name';
                    if($row[$altVar] == $val2)
                        return $row;
                }
                else
                    return $row;
            }
        }
    }

$array =array(
  array(
          'name' => 'flash',
          'type' => 'hero'
      ),

  array(
          'name' => 'zoom',
          'type' => 'villian'
      ),

  array(
          'name' => 'snart',
          'type' => 'antihero'
      ),
  array(
        'name' => 'flash',
        'type' => 'camera'
      )
  );

print_r(getValueMatch($array,'flash','camera'));
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [name] => flash
    [type] => camera
)
```

Example of reverse match (`type` instead of `name`):

```
print_r(getValueMatch($array,'antihero',false,'type'));
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [name] => snart
    [type] => antihero
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement from [RomanPerekhrest & RBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125110/10351006) Answer

---

```
<?php

function arraySearchMultiKeyVal($dataList = [], $arrKeyValFind = [], $is_return_key = false) {
    // Implement from answer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/45124763

    $index = array_keys($dataList, $arrKeyValFind);

    if ($index) {
        $key = $index[0];
        if ($is_return_key) {
            return $key;
        } else {

            return $dataList[$key];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$array_subjected_to_search = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'flash',
        'type' => 'hero'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'zoom',
        'type' => 'villian'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'snart',
        'type' => 'antihero'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'flash',
        'type' => 'camera'
    )
);

$result_key = arraySearchMultiKeyVal($array_subjected_to_search, ['type' => 'camera', 'name' => 'flash']);
print_r($result_key);
```

---

Will return

```
Array
(
    [name] => flash
    [type] => camera
)
```