# php array_keys() unexpected result with mutiple value filter

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a specific entry from a larger multidimensional array with another array of multiple values. For this I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125110/8118325
Actually the problem seems to be quite identical, but I still don't get a result.

[PHP Live Fiddle](https://onlinephp.io?s=5ZZRi9NAEMffD-47DEW4CjnuBJ_UQ9S0ctDIYWqF8yRsk2mzNtkNs5uc7XHfzDe_mLPpNcSrfbIBpS8h2Zn5z-z-yM68el2kxfHRE4OC4hQu4JvRKkow1gn2T77AHfSsLUhHWKGykVvuvYCe7_fg3nNWGWNEMm4sQfj-6l3b-HvgG39yGbIZvp54lkp8-pKTT4XBrdTHRwB37gG7dbyWvV2EP5r448a6YwPelrgS-Vo8qaTBLfWN2ceRnCAtwRdj3CETrdOEqJJSzY1wgmenopxZEvM_Kj9EfC6ViVPbclqXb6xQiaAECeVcSRNNMcHSsnhdkrCcSaIydue2oxyFko2_gBCp4gqagCTNokIs0LLHs63FSCqLpISVWonssQuWpDex52793vtLgOOge4BjGQy6AbhCaeEMrktjMcvc18zBQfrnsZ53iHUwvLz-1BnWQYaxJa1kDD5msnKER7J1dHsizHkWdR7mjDCUlKNarUGfunx40Iy5AQw-dsY4QGPEHGFApGnfYIeYZkgwRQkfRJyyNWU2P39MkXJpbcZqUGkFQZlZuRB8lkUmrJ1pyg8dOff8rpGzasyv7kz2zD0Mwhr6FelKMjOQCt7yQMRrNbIDZxt2N0pt2BqO2TfV5heGVTnH-np-jOS_Q9mamgF4cuYyuMldgCASy2iBS9Ovp2nvYaB3jhinmpvW94K7I2iFQGj4AoNbaVPgEHh-o25Ujz0rQVFS5kV_reuCfwE%2C&v=8.2.4)

What could be the problem here? To me, the problems in the linked thread and mine look very identical and yet I just can't get a result. Am I perhaps misunderstanding the function?

Comment: Please note that you are supposed to include a proper [mre] directly within your question, and not just dump the whole thing onto an external platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second element shouldn't have to be a list of arrays here and it should contain all the elements of the array. i.e

```
<?php
$search = json_decode('{
    "ice_event_code": "ADVIS",
    "ice_ric_code": "MSGPC",
    "ttpro_event_code": "DD",
    "ice_event_name": "Advise",
    "ice_ric_name": "Message processing",
    "ice_event_name_de": "Sendungsavise/-auftrag",
    "ice_ric_name_de": "SMS bei Provider in Bearbeitung",
    "ttpro_standardereignis_bedeutung": "Datendienst",
    "ttpro_event_code_meaning": "Data Service",
    "dhl_paket": 1,
    "dhl_paket_international": 0,
    "dhl_europaket": 0
  }',true);

$base = json_decode('[
  {
    "ice_event_code": "ADVIS",
    "ice_ric_code": "DLVDT",
    "ttpro_event_code": "DD",
    "ice_event_name": "Advise",
    "ice_ric_name": "DeLiVery DaTe",
    "ice_event_name_de": "Sendungsavise/-auftrag",
    "ice_ric_name_de": "Wunschtag",
    "ttpro_standardereignis_bedeutung": "Datendienst",
    "ttpro_event_code_meaning": "Data Service",
    "dhl_paket": 1,
    "dhl_paket_international": 1,
    "dhl_europaket": 0
  },
  {
    "ice_event_code": "ADVIS",
    "ice_ric_code": "DLVTM",
    "ttpro_event_code": "DD",
    "ice_event_name": "Advise",
    "ice_ric_name": "DeLiVery TiME",
    "ice_event_name_de": "Sendungsavise/-auftrag",
    "ice_ric_name_de": "Wunschzeit / Zustellzeitfenster",
    "ttpro_standardereignis_bedeutung": "Datendienst",
    "ttpro_event_code_meaning": "Data Service",
    "dhl_paket": 1,
    "dhl_paket_international": 0,
    "dhl_europaket": 0
  },
  {
    "ice_event_code": "ADVIS",
    "ice_ric_code": "EFIZU",
    "ttpro_event_code": "DD",
    "ice_event_name": "Advise",
    "ice_ric_name": "Electronic Delivery List",
    "ice_event_name_de": "Sendungsavise/-auftrag",
    "ice_ric_name_de": "Elektronische Firmenzustell-Liste",
    "ttpro_standardereignis_bedeutung": "Datendienst",
    "ttpro_event_code_meaning": "Data Service",
    "dhl_paket": 1,
    "dhl_paket_international": 0,
    "dhl_europaket": 0
  },
  {
    "ice_event_code": "ADVIS",
    "ice_ric_code": "MSGER",
    "ttpro_event_code": "DD",
    "ice_event_name": "Advise",
    "ice_ric_name": "Message Error",
    "ice_event_name_de": "Sendungsavise/-auftrag",
    "ice_ric_name_de": "Fehler bei Nachrichtenübermittlung von Multikanalplattform",
    "ttpro_standardereignis_bedeutung": "Datendienst",
    "ttpro_event_code_meaning": "Data Service",
    "dhl_paket": 1,
    "dhl_paket_international": 0,
    "dhl_europaket": 0
  },
  {
    "ice_event_code": "ADVIS",
    "ice_ric_code": "MSGPC",
    "ttpro_event_code": "DD",
    "ice_event_name": "Advise",
    "ice_ric_name": "Message processing",
    "ice_event_name_de": "Sendungsavise/-auftrag",
    "ice_ric_name_de": "SMS bei Provider in Bearbeitung",
    "ttpro_standardereignis_bedeutung": "Datendienst",
    "ttpro_event_code_meaning": "Data Service",
    "dhl_paket": 1,
    "dhl_paket_international": 0,
    "dhl_europaket": 0
  },
  {
    "ice_event_code": "ADVIS",
    "ice_ric_code": "MSGST",
    "ttpro_event_code": "DD",
    "ice_event_name": "Advise",
    "ice_ric_name": "Message sent",
    "ice_event_name_de": "Sendungsavise/-auftrag",
    "ice_ric_name_de": "Nachricht zugestellt",
    "ttpro_standardereignis_bedeutung": "Datendienst",
    "ttpro_event_code_meaning": "Data Service",
    "dhl_paket": 1,
    "dhl_paket_international": 0,
    "dhl_europaket": 0
  }]',true);
  
$entry = array_keys($base,$search);
echo "Expect one result with key 4\n\n";
var_dump($entry);
```

Output:

```
Expect one result with key 4

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution :) I have since bypassed it with a loop and will have to stick with it as I don't have all the elements available for the search.